# Prediction Algorithm for system Load based on history data

Tags: algorithm, prediction

I am creating a system load prediction system based on previous data. I have the data in the following format for multiple days:

```
Time    Cpu usage

00     20%
01     20%
03     22%
04     20%
05     23%
06     30%
07     35%
08     40%
09     50%.......
```

Given such data for many Mondays I want to predict cpu usage for the next Monday based on given data. I am search of some kind of an algorithm. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple algorithm to achieve this is Polynomial Regression http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression.

You can run it on any spreadsheet, statistical package/ library.

Comment: There are also youtube videos about how to do it in Excel: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkuX2jTXatE http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJCKd98lKEQ And if you are using LibreOffice or OpenOffice, you can use this: http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/download/file.php?id=735&sid=1e5296a202e5e915ce5a165256d6110c

Answer (score 0):

You may consider looking to finance for predictive algorithms, try perhaps looking into the Mean Reversion algorithm to predict the load.

I would use Python and the pandas library to quickly apply functions to your data and get the result your looking for.

Comment: Would some kind of extrapolation work well here? Have any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem that you are trying to solve is one of the problems that are studied in the field of [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). Coursera has a [great online course](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) about that.

There is a software, [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), that has many machine learning algorithms and a [nice graphical interface](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/gui_explorer.html).

Comment: Could you point me to the exact algorithm...I don't think I have time to go through the entire course for this problem!! I have to get this project going. It would be nice if you could point me to some links which would have some explanations for it. Thanks!!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry. The problem was uning `replaceAll` instead of `replace`, because `replaceAll` works with Java regular expressions.